# How can I show cursor coordinates as I move the mouse over a contour plot?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, formatting

How can I show cursor coordinates as I move the mouse over the contour plot in the result displayed by evaluation the following:

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[91.4 + (91.4 - t) (0.023 v - 0.304 Sqrt[v] - 0.474), 
    {v, 4,  45}, {t, -60, 30}, 
    ContourLabels -> True], 
  {{spot, {30, 15}}, {5, -60}, {45, 25}, Locator}]
```

Additionally, I would like to show bigger levels.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** You can also use [`GetCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/GetCoordinates.html) from the right-click menu:

```
f[v_, t_] := 91.4 + (91.4 - t) (0.023 v - 0.304 Sqrt[v] - 0.474);
ContourPlot[f[v, t], {v, 4, 45}, {t, -60, 30}, ContourLabels -> True]
```

[image]

Use [CoordinatesToolOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoordinatesToolOptions.html) to customize the content displayed:

```
ContourPlot[f[v, t], {v, 4, 45}, {t, -60, 30}, ContourLabels -> True, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> 
    Function[pt, Row[{"f(", pt[[1]], ",", pt[[2]] ") = ", f @@ pt}]]}]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot[91.4 + (91.4 - t) (0.023 v - 0.304 Sqrt[v] - 0.474), 
              {v, 4, 45}, {t, -60, 30}, 
              ContourLabels -> True, PlotLabel -> Style[spot, "Panel", 16]],
   {{spot, {30, 15}}, {5, -60}, {45, 25}, Locator}]
```

or

```
Manipulate[Labeled[ContourPlot[91.4 + (91.4 - t) (0.023 v - 0.304 Sqrt[v] - 0.474), 
                               {v, 4, 45}, {t, -60, 30}, ContourLabels -> True], 
                   Style[spot, "Panel", 16], Top], 
           {{spot, {30, 15}}, {5, -60}, {45, 25}, Locator}]
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Manipulate[
 Column@{Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics", "Mouse not in graphics!"]],
    ContourPlot[91.4 + (91.4 - t) (0.023 v - 0.304 Sqrt[v] - 0.474), {v, 4, 45}, {t, -60, 30}, 
               ContourLabels -> True]}, 
 {{spot, {30, 15}}, {5, -60}, {45, 25}, Locator}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why not just `Dynamic[spot]`?

Comment: @Kuba Because that doesn't follow the mouse position continuously. It is updated only when you click.